# chmod Operation not permitted　というエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsl

参考書で勉強をしていて`rails new scaffold_app -d PostgreSQL`のコマンドを実行したところ、

```
reate  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
/home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/actions.rb:260: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1 in PATH, mode 040777
error: chmod on /mnt/c/Code1/scaffold_app/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  bin/yarn
Traceback (most recent call last):
        31: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        30: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        29: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        28: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        27: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        26: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        24: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        23: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        22: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        21: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        20: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        19: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
        18: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        17: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        16: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        15: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        14: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        13: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        12: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        11: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:305:in `create_bin_files'
        10: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:159:in `build'
         9: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:94:in `bin'
         8: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:19:in `chmod'
         7: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:154:in `chmod'
         6: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:939:in `chmod_R'
         5: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:939:in `each'
         4: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:940:in `block in chmod_R'
         3: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1370:in `preorder_traverse'
         2: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:942:in `block (2 levels) in chmod_R'
         1: from /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1243:in `chmod'
/home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1243:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /mnt/c/Code1/scaffold_app/bin (Errno::EPERM)
```

というような表示が出てきて作成されないファイルがあり、困っています。

- ruby 2.5.1
- rails 5.2.1
- wsl経由のUbuntu
- windowsのバージョン　1903

を使っています。
色々調べてみたのですが自分では解決できないので質問させて頂きました。ご教授願います。

**<追記>**
どうやらファイルのパーミッションに関するエラーなのではないかと現在考えているのですが、そこからどうしたらよいか途方に暮れています。
scaffold_appの権限がrootになっておりそこをユーザー名に変更したらよいのかと思い、

```
sudo chown -R tarou scaffold_app
```

を実行したのですが権限が変更されないです。どうしたらよいのでしょうか。
以下がファイルのパーミッションになります。

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Nov  7 02:21 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Nov  7 01:24 ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Nov  7 02:21 scaffold_app/
```

Comment: 間違っていたらすみません、もしかしてWSL経由でのUbuntuですか？(/mnt/c/....)と言うディレクトリパスがあったので、気になりました。もしそうならその旨も記載しておいた方が、的を射たアドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: wsl経由で使っています。ご指摘ありがとうございます。追記しておきます！

Comment: WSLは、Windows 10のバージョン(設定⇒システム⇒バージョン情報の一番下にあるWindowsの仕様の「バージョン」に書いてある1809とか1903とかのこと)によって動作が変わってくる場合があります。Windows 10のバージョンも質問に明記してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記します

Answer (score 2):

エラーに出ているパス(`/mnt/c`)は恐らくWSL環境からWindowsのファイルシステムを参照しているかと思いますが、`chmod` 等でパーミッション(アクセス権限)を操作するには、メタデータを有効にした状態でマウントする必要があるようです。

`metadata` オプションを付けてドライブをマウント

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/c
$ sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

なお、WSL build 17093 以降であれば、[設定ファイルに記述しておく](https://qiita.com/remin/items/a726128ab388cb73d9ee)ことでオプションを恒久化する方法もあるようです。

参考:

- [PHP chmod(): Operation not permitted · Issue #3172 · microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3172)
- [Chmod/Chown WSL Improvements | Windows Command Line](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/)
- [WSLからマウントしたWindowsのドライブでchmodしたい - Qiita](https://qiita.com/remin/items/a726128ab388cb73d9ee)

Comment: 上記のコマンドを使うことで解決することができました。オプションを恒久化する設定も行います。丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

リンク切れしてたので同様の内容を貼っておきます

恒常化について
https://rdrgn.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/05/18/000000

補足 /etc/wsl.conf 等々のある場所
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/wsl-config