# chmod でアクセス権限の変更ができない

Tags: linux, wsl

`chmod 455 file` で指定のファイルを
`-r--r-xr-x`としたいのですが
`-r-xr-xr-x`となってしまい、ユーザの実行のパーミッションの変更が出来ません。
ファイルオーナーは自分です。

ちなみに書き込みのパーミッションだけは変更が出来て、
`chmod 000`をあてても
`-r-xr-xr-x`
となり、111でも444でも555でも同じ結果が返ってきてしまいます。書き込み権限はu、g、oで変更可能なのを確認したので書き込みの権限だけ変更できる状態になってると思われます。

```
$ chmod 000 file
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 ユーザ名 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 ユーザ名 ..
-r-xr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 file
```

というかんじです、よろしくお願いします。
環境は Windows10 で、bash on windows (WSL) を使用しています。

Comment: ヌメリックモードだけでなく、`chmod a=0 file`などのレターセレクトを使っても同じ結果になります。

Comment: 参考:[chmod doesn't work? · Issue #81 · microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/81)

Comment: 参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/60299 , https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/44243

Comment: `WSL`タグ付いてますが, WSLの話でしょうか？
"git-bash for windows"https://git-scm.com/ のつもりだったのですが (WSLの話なら使ったこともないので回答消しますが)

Comment: @oriri `WSL` タグは私が編集で付けたものです。私も初めは `git-bash` かなとも思いましたが、質問中に "bash for windows" と書かれていたので WSL を付けた次第です。

Comment: @cubick "git-bash for windows" はよく bash for windows と呼ばてるのでそれかなと。
"Bash **ON** Windows" だと…(調べてみると) WSLの旧名らしいので違うのかなと。とりあえず反応あるまで置いときます

Comment: @oriri bash on windowsでした、、編集しておきました。とりあえずおとなしくmacでやろうと思います。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### WSL (Bash ON Windows) の場合

コメントにある URLが参考になるでしょう。
(ファイルシステム内に, chmodで扱う情報を, 基本持っていない点においては以下の情報も参考になることもあるかも)

#### (Git) Bash for Windows の場合

UNIX系 OSの場合, ファイルシステムにパーミッションを持ちます。
たとえば Linux の ext-fs (現在は ext4など)
しかし Windowsの FATなどは, パーミッション(owner/userとか groupとか otherなど)ではなく, ReadOnly とか System とか(？) 限られた情報しか持ちません。(起源がもともと個人ユーザーという面もあるのでしょう)

参考: Windows コマンド [attrib](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib)

なので, `chmod` で FAT系ファイルシステムにアクセスしても UNIXと同等には扱えません。
ext4の USBメモリーなど用意しマウントすればもしかするとパーミッションにアクセス可能になるかもしれません
(bash for windows のコマンドの中身が手抜きでない限り)

また, Linux上から, FATの USBメモリーにアクセスした場合も, 同様に, 変更できそうに見えて変更できないことが多々あります。
そもそも FATを `mount`するときに, 次のようなオプションを指定するくらいなので

> uid=value と gid=value
> すべてのファイルの所有者とグループを設定する (デフォルトはカレントプロセスの uid と gid)。